# How to get substring ends with multiple characters and have at least n characters

Tags: python, regex

I want to get substring that ends with `'d', 'g', 'y'` and the substring contains at least `five` characters.

`str = 'Did David go swimming yesterday'`

The result should be `'David', 'swimming' and 'yesterday'`

How to use `regex` to do it?

Thank you.

Comment: `[i for i in str if len(i) >= 5 and i[-1] in 'dgy']`

Comment: Did you try anything already? Doesn't seem that complex.

Comment: `did` should also be part of your output as it ends with `d`

Comment: @PrashantKumar the questions asks for "at least five characters."

Comment: Ohh missed that part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regex: `[^\s]{4,}[dgy]\b`

- `[^\s]` to match any non-whitespace character.
- `{4,}` to match at least 4 of the characters described above.
- `[dgy]` to match the last character of the word.
- `\b` to match a word boundary.

I would recommend checking out https://regexr.com/ to help you solve a regex problem.

Comment: Why doesn't it work for this : `[^\s]{4,}(d|g|y)`?

Comment: Wouldn't this match substring that have an d, g or y somewhere in the substring itself after position 4? OP mentioned the substring should end with those characters. I could be wrong =). mayb `\b` at the end would be a good addition?

Comment: That should work, unless the "(d|g|y)" part is causing an issue. Also I just realised you would want d, g, or y to be the last character, ill update my answer.

Comment: @JvdV yeah I realized the same thing, thanks for the "\b" suggestion